# Is there a unix scripting file checking Key?

Tags: shell-script, test, documentation

Is there a key that explains theese letters such as `-n`, `-d`, etc all mean ?

Example:

```
if [[ -d ${directory_name} ]]; then ...; fi
```

What is the `-d` or where do I find a key?

Example:

```
while [[ -n ${variable_name} ]]; do ...; done
```

what is the `-n` mean??

Is there a guide that explains what all of these `-n`, `-e`, `-a`, `-d`, `-s`, `-h`, etc?

I do a lot of Unix shell scripting modifications, and I've seen these arguments used inside the loops or if then statements on variables and file locations etc.

I'm looking for a place that explains each of the arguments as mentioned above for scripting.

Comment: Search for _conditional expressions_ in the man page of your shell, [eg `zsh`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Conditional-Expressions.html)

Comment: or `man test`, depending on your OS/distro  (only if your shell is *not* providing a built-in `test`).

Comment: "Conditional Expressions" was what i was looking for in the man page. Thanks for your quick reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want the TLDP page for BASH,

advanced bash: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/index.html

beginner bash: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/index.html

what you were asking is about **file test operators** and can be found here: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html

and also **bash conditional expressions** which can found here: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html

```
-d  file is a directory
-f  file is a regular file
-e  file exists
-s  file size is not zero
-b  file is a block device
-h  file is a symbolic link
-w  file has write permissions for user executing this bash statement
{there are more}

#!/bin/bash
if [ -e $1 ] && [ -w $1 ]; then
   echo "the file you entered was "$1" and it exists and you have write permission to it"
else
   echo "condition failed for exist and for write permission"
fi
```

Comment: Wow!! Thanks for your help and the resources. Thats exactly what I wanted!!! Thanks much!

Answer (score 4):

I believe you should find everything in details in the man page of your shell (e.g. `man bash`).

Moreover, `bash`, for one, has a builtin command named `help`. Just give the command in parameter. Here the command is `[[` and `help [[` redirects to the command `test` (a.k.a. `[`), therefore `help test` will give you what you need.

Finally, builtins often have their standalone counterparts in `/bin` and their are generally provided with a manpage => `man [` or `man test`

Comment: Perfect!! This is what I needed!! I was originally doing "man -n" etc and getting nowhere. Thank you for providing the answer I needed. I wish I could mark this as the correct answer as well.

Comment: You can do a `man xxx`, but only on a command, not on an option. So, you must first identify the command which is the first word after `if` or `while`. For bash builtins, use `help` instead.